# How to associate sendgrid webhook sg_message_id to sent mail?

Tags: webhooks, sendgrid

Sendgrid webhook has `sg_message_id`
But the response of Web API v2 when sending mail doesn't have `sg_message_id`.
In fact, there is only message showing only `success` or failed.

So, how do i associate between sent mail and the webhook callback?

I have check the past questions in SO but it doesn't provide be the solution for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use unique arguments.  Take your unique ID (like primary key) and give it to sendgrid API during sending email.  You will get it back in the event webhook.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/unique-arguments

When you want to use "unique arguments" through SMTP you should be able to do so using the `X-SMTPAPI` message header.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/building-an-x-smtpapi-header

Comment: This must be accepted as answer. Thanks Dmitry! Actually this is something that must be added to the Sendgrid docs!!!

Comment: Is there something analogous for the v3 SendGrid API?

Comment: @ktingle yes, for the v3 API, use `custom_args`

Comment: Note: if your hook fails and you need retrospect data you will need to pay undisclosed amount for [Email Activity API](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages). (Price is not shown for free users for some reason).

Comment: [Here's the v3 SendGrid documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event#unique-arguments-and-custom-arguments) for `custom_args` / `unique_args`.

Answer (score 23):

**EDIT**: The best practice seems to be using [custom arguments](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/412) (see [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html#-Unique-Arguments-and-Custom-Arguments)). Which is not apparent from the documentation (as of today).

---

In Web API v3, the response includes a special header `X-Message-Id` (see https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/x_message_id.html).

This can be later matched with `sg_message_id` in webhook: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/message_id.html

The documentation does not make it clear, but the `X-Message-Id` header is actually not equal to `sg_message_id`, but it is a prefix of `sg_message_id`.

For example:

- `X-Message-Id  = "MUvGg3V1ThOu3oe8eRqFrA"`
- `sg_message_id = "MUvGg3V1ThOu3oe8eRqFrA.filter0001p2iad2-21183-5AF0BD9B-E.0"`

Comment: I would advise against this; it is entirely possible that this type of matching does not work 100% of the time. As you noted in your edit a custom argument avoids this possibility

Comment: Me too, actually. At the time, the documentation told everywhere people should use those X-Message-Id, however the implementation was all kind of weird...

Comment: After those 30 days - if user will do any activity with that message (like open it again or click) after i.e. 40 days (so beyond 30 days limit) will that message come back to email activity history?

Comment: I would not use it. This pattern can be changed by sendgrid any day any time. Don't depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

The Web APIv2 call that sends out the email only responds with a **{message :"success"}** answer indeed, but the **sg_message_id** is not generated at that point. The API call answer simply acknowledges that the email was sent to SendGrid for processing.

The email is sent to SendGrid, and there it receives the **sg_message_id** value that is provided through the Event Webhook posts.

Comment: So, it is noway to match the request & webhook? what do u think?